# Prime-to-$p$ quotients of ${\rm PSL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{p})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, p-adic-groups

Let $p$ be a prime and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ the ring of $p$-adic integers. Let ${\rm PSL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{p})={\rm SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{p})/\{\pm 1\}$ be the projective special linear group over $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Recall that the *maximal pro-prime-to-$p$ quotient* of a profinite group $G$ is $G^{(p')}:=\varprojlim G/N$ where $N$ runs over all normal open subgroup $N$ such that the index $[G:N]$ is not divisible by $p$.

My question is the following:

> Is there a finite quotient $H$ of ${\rm PSL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{p})$ such that order of the group $H$ is not divisible by $p$ and $H$ has a non-cyclic abelian subgroup? What is ${\rm PSL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{p})^{(p')}$?

Comment: The kernel of the map from $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ to $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is pro-$p$ so you can easily reduce your problem to the latter. Here $\mathbb{F}_p$ is the field with $p$ elements.

Comment: Following the previous comment, notice also that ${\rm PSL}(2, \mathbb{F}_{p})$ is generated by its elements of order $p$, so the answer to your first question as stated is "no".